# Problem solving a 4 by 4 linear system with infinite solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have a question here. The following is a 4 by 4 system of linear equations which has infinitely many solutions.

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x+y+3z+t=0 \\ 
x-y-z-t=0 \\ 
3x+y+5z+3t=0 \\
x+5y+11z+8t=0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

An online calculator gave me these solutions:
$t = 0, x = - r_1, y = -2 r_1, z = r_1$, where $r_1$ is a parameter.

However, how did they solve this? It's kinda complicated for me, because what I'd do is I'd isolate "$x$" from the second equation $(x=y+z+t)$, then I would plug that into the first equation and so on...

Can someone help? Thank you and sorry for taking your time !

Comment: this is exactly what linear algebra was invented for. Look up reduced row echelon form, and gaussian elimination.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $x=y+z+t$ in the first equation and you have

$2y+4z+2t=0 \\ \Rightarrow y+2z=-t$

Substitute $x=y+z+t$ in the third equation and you have

$4y+8z+6t=0$

Then substitute $y+2z=-t$ and you get $t=0$. So $y=-2z$ and $x=y+z$.

Substitute $x=y+z$, $y=-2z$ and $t=0$ in the fourth equation and you have

$0=0$

So the fourth equation tells us nothing new (this is because the fourth equation is a linear combination of the other three equations).

So we have $y=-2z$ and $x=y+z=-z$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the matrix of the linear system and put it in *reduced row echelon form*:
\begin{align}
&\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1&1&3&1\\1&-1&-1&-1\\3&1&5&3\\1&5&11&8
\end{array}\right]\rightsquigarrow
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1&1&3&1\\0&-2&-4&-2\\0&-2&-4&0\\0&4&8&7
\end{array}\right]\rightsquigarrow
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1&1&3&1\\0&-2&-4&-2\\0&0&0&2\\0&0&0&3
\end{array}\right]\rightsquigarrow
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1&1&3&1\\0&1&2&1\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&3
\end{array}\right] \\[1ex]
&{}\rightsquigarrow\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1&1&3&0\\0&1&2&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0
\end{array}\right]\rightsquigarrow
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1&0&1&0\\0&1&2&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0
\end{array}\right].
\end{align}